# Sum column which has both numbers and text using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sum

I have a column which contains both numbers and text, and I'm trying to find the sum of the values.

I tried this sum function below, but it didn't work.  Please can you advise what else I could try?

```
df["Price"].sum()
```

[image]

Comment: @KalanaErandaJayasuriya: How it is a duplicate question, Please  read the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pd.to_numeric`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Price": ["Nil", "Na", 1,2,3,4,5, "Null"]})

print(df[pd.to_numeric(df['Price'], errors='coerce').notnull()].sum())
#or
print(pd.to_numeric(df['Price'], errors='coerce').dropna().sum())
```

**Output:**

```
Price    15.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this

`df.Price[df.Price.astype(str).str.isnumeric()].sum()`

Answer (score 0):

You could use if all your values were numbers:

```
print(sum(df['Price']))
```

but in your case you can use this:

```
import numbers
print(sum([x for x in df['Price'] if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)]))
```